# Who is winning is this game of chess?

Tags: online-chess

[image]

What do you think are the chances for the black to win?

Answer (score 5):

It's game over for Black. Down by material, mating attack, zero counterplay etc. The Black's rook is under attacked.

> 1...Rd6 2.e5 Qxe5 3.Qg4+ Qf5 4.Qxh5 winning easily

1-0 unless White makes a horrible mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Black is down in material by a couple of pawns and the black King is very weak.

Unless there are any immediate tactics (doesn't look like there are, but haven't checked with an engine), white should win this.